# How use CKSource.FileSystem.Local in a ASP.NET (not MVC) Solution

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, ckfinder

I found this doc for [Manual Integration](https://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/integration.html#integration_ckeditor_manual) but is MVC only.

I tried following the integration logic for ASP.NET but I can not do the same thing.

Does anyone know of a document that shows how to do this?

I need to use the CKSource.FileSystem.Local, but the main problem is that we can not configure the CKfinder 3 connector to work with CKEditor 4.6 with ASP.NET WebForms.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what `CKSource.FileSystem.Local` does. Never used it. But it looks like you want the popup windows to work for inserting images and files as a link in the formatted text. So here is a complete working example so you don't need that plugin.

First we start with the page containing the Editor. Note the use of `filebrowserBrowseUrl` and `filebrowserImageBrowseUrl` that point to a separate page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text="<p>This is a demo text.</p>"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>', {
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/CKFileBrowser.aspx?type=doc',
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/CKFileBrowser.aspx?type=img'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Next is the CKFileBrowser.aspx page that will display the images and files to be selected. We'll use a `GridView` to display all the files and a `DataList` for the images because it can easily display multiple columns.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="filesHolder">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# string.Format("{0:N0}", Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Length")) / 1024) %> kb
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="10" CssClass="thumbnailHolder">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img src="<%=defaultFolder %>/<%# Eval("Name") %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var funcNum = '<%= Request.QueryString["CKEditorFuncNum"] %>';
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr').click(function () {
            var fileUrl = '<%= baseUrl %>' + $(this).find("td:first").text().trim();
            window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, fileUrl);
            window.close();
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= DataList1.ClientID %> img').click(function () {
            var fileUrl = $(this).attr('src').trim();
            window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, fileUrl);
            window.close();
        })
    });
</script>

<style>
    .filesHolder tr {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .thumbnailHolder {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    }

        .thumbnailHolder img {
            max-width: 250px;
            max-height: 125px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
</style>
```

Note here the usage of `Request.QueryString["CKEditorFuncNum"]`. It identifies the correct Editor for the callback.
The jQuery will bind the `click` functions to the `<tr>` and `<img>` tags to initiate the callback to the parent page and send the correct file/path back to the editor.

Finally the code behind of the CKFileBrowser.aspx popup

```
public string defaultFolder;
public string baseUrl;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set the default folder and the url for the files
    defaultFolder = "/files";
    baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + defaultFolder + "/";

    bool images_only = false;

    //check the type of popup
    if (Request.QueryString["type"] != null)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["type"].ToString() == "img")
        {
            images_only = true;
        }
    }

    //build the popup items
    findTheFiles(images_only);
}

private void findTheFiles(bool images_only)
{
    //get all the files in the folder
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(defaultFolder));
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();

    if (images_only == true)
    {
        //show only jpg or gif in the datalist
        DataList1.DataSource = files.Where(x => (x.Extension.ToLower() == ".jpg") || (x.Extension.ToLower() == ".gif")).ToList();
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        //display all files in the gridview
        GridView1.DataSource = files;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At this moment we are implementing your code. I will back soon to post the results.

Comment: We're sorry, but we can not consider your code proposal as a response to our problem. You are not using CKFinder in your code. What you do is create a page "CKFileBrowser.aspx"
What we really need is an example of integrating CKFinder with CKEditor in ASP.NEt Webforms.
We only found examples implemented with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: No problem, but if I look at the url you provided, the only difference is that I created the file browser itself but when you use `CKFinder` the only thing you need to change would be pointing towards the different url (`/ckfinder/ckfinder.html` instead of `CKFileBrowser.aspx`)

Comment: On the CKEditor side, it is clear how to do the integration, but our problem is in creating the CKFinder connector with the CKSource.LocalStorage class.

We did not find any examples of this integration with ASP.NET WebForms and the documentation is very bad.